# Opensnowmap.org tile not downloading

Tags: openstreetmap, mobile

Currently I am trying to show ski map on my mobile application written on flutter/dart.
I found **http://www.opensnowmap.org/** site that show lifts and pistes all around the world.

I tried the link below as it is mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52920570/openskimap-tile-not-loading/53246539#53246539. 
However 
[http://www.opensnowmap.org/pistes/{z}/{x}/{y}.png](http://www.opensnowmap.org/pistes/%7Bz%7D/%7Bx%7D/%7By%7D.png) seems not working. Is there anyone knows the solution or using opensnowmap service currently.

Comment: Do you have any info on using OSM in Flutter? Packages, tutorials, documentation? All URLs gratefully accepted. Thanks in advance

Comment: I have a piece of code that I used osm maps https://github.com/berkantay/snowguru_app/blob/master/lib/skiMapSection.dart if you have futher questions please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct tile URL is `https://tiles.opensnowmap.org/pistes/{z}/{x}/{y}.png`. You can check which images your browser is loading.

Please make sure to respect the tile usage policy. You can find it at https://www.opensnowmap.org/ -> About -> Tile Use:

> - use a valid referer
> - prohibit bulk download from your app
> - credit Data (c) www.openstreetmap.org & contributors ODBL and www.opensnowmap.org CC-BY-SA.

Comment: as a sample I am heading to <https://tiles.opensnowmap.org/pistes/10/10/10.png> but it is blank actually. I do not know whether it is based on because there is no lift there or anything else?

Comment: Yes, there is neither a piste nor any lift at this location. See https://tiles.opensnowmap.org/pistes/15/17348/11518.png as an example for containing both pistes and lifts.

Comment: huge thanks @scai, cheers

Comment: i would like to ask one more think, is it possible to get base_snow_map view?

Comment: Maybe. The tile URL for the base snow map is `https://tiles.opensnowmap.org/base_snow_map/{z}/{x}/{y}.png`. However I'm getting an access denied image. I guess they block other referrers. In this case you have to choose a different base map or get into contact with the opensnowmap guys.

Comment: I think so, thank you for your help. I sent them an email about that, let you know in case of any update